# Triangle angle bisector problem: Finding area

Tags: geometry

I need help on a geometry challenge from [Instagram user gercekboss](https://instagram.com/p/CTLgH45DYJP) that really stumps me.

[image]

I know some relevant theorems, such as the angle bisector theorem, but I just can't for the life of me figure out how to apply them.

Can anyone give any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Defining $x,y,z$ as shown in the figure above, we can write the following equation from the angle bisector theorem.

$6/x = (5 + y) / (9 + z)$

$5/y = (6 + x)/(9 + z)$

$9 / z = (6 + x)/(5 + y)$

therefore,

$6 (9+z) = x (5 + y)$

$5 (9+z) = y (6 + x)$

$9 (5 + y) = z (6 + x)$

These equation have only one valid solution, namely, $x = 9, y = 5, z = 6$

Hence the sides of the triangle, are $15, 10, 15$

the semi-perimeter is $s =\frac{1}{2} (15 + 10 + 15) = 20 $

Therefore, by Heron's formula, the area is given by

$\text{Area} = \sqrt{ s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) } =\sqrt{ 20 (5)(5)(10) } = 50 \sqrt{2} $

Comment: How did you find the solution to the system of equations? That is my main hang-up. Because I know I can just re-derive Heron's formula using pythagoras.

Comment: I used [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)